# CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent vs Assert.Equals()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, equality

```
public void NumericListCanBeSorted()
{
  var sorted = sort.SortNumbers(nums);
  Assert.AreEqual(sorted, nums);
}

public List<int> SortNumbers(List<int> nums)
    {
        List<int> sortedList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Count; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] > nums[j])
                {
                    //Swapping values
                    nums[i] = nums[i] + nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[i] - nums[j];
                    nums[i] = nums[i] - nums[j];
                }
            }
            sortedList.Add(nums[i]);
        }
        return sortedList;
    }

Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:     <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]>. 
      Actual :<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]>.
```

The datatypes of expected and actual are same. Still test failed. Cannot understand why? Can someone please help me know the reason.Moreover, it works for the following function.

```
  public List<int> SortNumbers(List<int> nums)
    {
        List<int> sortedList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Count; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] > nums[j])
                {
                    //Swapping values
                    nums[i] = nums[i] + nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[i] - nums[j];
                    nums[i] = nums[i] - nums[j];
                }
            }
        }
        sortedList = nums;
        return sortedList;
    }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Reference type comparisons.

Try using CollectionAssert.AreEqual or CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent.aspx

Here's what happens:

You use `Assert.AreEqual(List<int>, List<int>)`, of which, the CLR/.NET goes in and says, "is the reference of List 1 the same as List 2?" The result is no, therefore, the CLR/.NET returns false.

`CollectionAssert` enumerates the arrays (which is what Lists are internally) and determines if they have the same items. `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` checks that they have the same items in the same order. `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` checks that they have the same items, in any order.

***ANY*** array/List/Dictionary *MUST* use `CollectionAssert` for such comparisons.

For example:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
List<int> l2 = l1;
Assert.AreEqual(l1, l2);
```

This will result in true, due to `l2` having been set to the same reference as `l1`.

However:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
List<int> l2 = new List<int>();
Assert.AreEqual(l1, l2);
```

This will result in a **false** due to `l2` having been made a *NEW* reference to a *NEW* object.
Whereas:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(l1, l2);
```

This will result in a **true** in either situation above. This is because the CLR/.NET actually goes through the list and inventories it, essentially.

Another edit, because I wanted to clarify further; you can also use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`, which will not guarantee the items in the same order, but will simply guarantee that the arrays/Lists/Dictionaries have the same quantities of the same items. I.e.:

```
1,2,3,3,2,1
1,3,2,2,3,1
```

This will result in **true** with `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`, but **false** with `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit in detail. I am looking for AreEqual.

Comment: @SravanKumar sortedList != nums therefore it fails - you need to compare item by item, not the two array objects. Debug and try checking if sortedList == nums in the immediate or watch windows.

Comment: @Danny varod sortedList is indeed equal to nums (Both contain the sorted numbers).

Comment: @EBrown's explanation is what i missed. Thanks EBrown